# With CoreData, how can I determine if an NSManagedObject is in a specific context?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

In core data, you must only manipulate an object via the context from which it was fetched.  This means, if you have two contexts, let's call them mainContext and backGround context, backGround context must only update objects from backgroundContext and mainContext must only update objects from mainContext.  This sounds simple enough.

Here is my problem.  I have an object from an unknown context, how can I determine if the object is from mainContext or backgroundContext??   I know that the managedObject has a pointer to its managedObjectContext called "managedObjectContext", but I don't know how to compare that to my pointers to mainContext and backgroundContext in order to see which one it is in?  Please help.

Comment: [myObject.managedObjectContext isEqual:mainObjectContext]? I should add that if you want pointer comparison rather than object equality, I believe you want ==

Answer (score 0):

somewhere you have:

```
id yourMainContext = ...
id yourBGContext = ...
```

now to check the context:

```
id yourObjectsContext = yourObject.managedObjectContext;
BOOL equalToMain = [yourObjectsContext isEqual:yourMainContext];
BOOL equalToBG = [yourObjectsContext isEqual:yourBGContext];
```

---

## Full solution

to store the context of the mainQueue/BGQueue you could also use function `dispatch_queue_set_specific`

somewhere you have:

```
id yourMainContext = ...
dispatch_queue_set_specific(dispatch_get_main_queue(), "MOC", yourMainContext);
```

and somewhere else

```
id yourBGContext = ...
dispatch_queue_set_specific(theBGQueue, "MOC", yourBGContext);
```

now LATER to check the context:

```
id queueContext = dispatch_get_specific("MOC");
assert(queueContext);

id yourObjectsContext = yourObject.managedObjectContext;
BOOL equalToQueue = [yourObjectsContext isEqual:queueContext];
//SAFE TO MODIFY
```

Answer (score 0):

Now in IOS8 NSManagedObjectContext have a property name you can use it and compare:

[yourObjectsContext.name isEqualToString:yourBGContext.name]